# Mouse Over in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, qt-designer

I made the gui in Qt Designer and then converted it into python using pyuic4. Now i want to capture the mouseover event on the buttons.

```
class window_b(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(window_b, self).__init__(parent)
        window_a.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui = Ui_Form_window_b()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
    def mouseMoveEvent (self,event):
        source= self.sender()
        #print source.name()
        # The action I want to do when the mouse is over the button:
        source.setStyleSheet("background-color:#66c0ff;border-radiu‌​s: 5px;")
```

I put the `mouseMoveEvent` method on the widget and I want to detect which button on the Dialog sent the mouseOver event. I tried `source.name()` but it throws me this error

```
print source.name()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: rename source = self.sender() to source = event.name() cause currently you try to get sender of window_b (this is what self point to)

Comment: What do you want to do in case of a mouse over on a certain button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sender()` is only useful for signals but the mouse hovering is an event not a signal (actually 2 events: `QEvent.Enter` and `QEvent.Leave`).

And to be able to handle events outside the buttons that received them, you need to install your `window_b` instance as an event filter for each button.

```
class window_b(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(window_b, self).__init__(parent)
        window_a.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui = Ui_Form_window_b()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

        # Get all the buttons (you probably don't want all of them)
        buttons = self.findChildren(QtGui.QAbstractButton)
        for button in buttons:
            button.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            print("mouse entered %s" % obj.objectName())
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
            print("mouse leaved %s" % obj.objectName())    
        return super(window_b, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

If you only need to change the style, you can simply use the pseudo-state ":hover" in a stylesheet (from the designer, or in the constructor with `self.setStyleSheet`):

```
QPushButton {
     border: 1px solid black;   
     padding: 5px;
}
QPushButton:hover {   
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;   
    background-color:#66c0ff;
}
```

Comment: It helps but later i want to change the colour of that widget i do get the object name and i thought that once i got that i will putt this line of code and it will work but its not    self.ui.object.objectName().setStyleSheet("background-color:#66c0ff;border-radius: 5px;")

Comment: @avaris i just want to change the color of the button through this self.ui.object.objectName().setStyleSheet("background-color:#66c0ff;border-radius: 5px;")

Comment: @user1224233 There was an error in my code with the parameter name, it should have been "obj" instead of "object". But objectName() returns a string, you need the modify the object itself: `obj.setStyleSheet(...)`. I added an alternative solution now that you indicated you only wanted to change the style of the button.